# What can I do when my webserver (Apache/2.2.3 on Centos 5.5) takes longer than 10 seconds to respond to a nagios web request on port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, process, zombie

Hyperic says there is a zombie process around the same time.
How can I figure out what process it is and go from there?

It usually happens every day between Midnight and 1AM, but it has occured around 11am as well.

Let me know if I can provide more details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a transient event causing this.  A service restart, a log rotating, a disk blocking, a saturated ASIC on a switch or a DNS lookup failure.  See if you can capture the event occurring with a rotating capture set using tshark (Wireshark command-line) and it could provide the detail needed to see if it's a DNS lookup stalling, or the Apache server stalling, or the response leaving the Apache server, and not making it back to the Nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.2.3 is extremely old.

You are advised to upgrade to the latest version as it may fix your issue.

Comment: Do you have anything more specific than "it may" fix the issue?  Such as a changelog entry or commit log?